# Looking to disable MacBook internal keyboard. Newest OS doesn't seem to support older solutions

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, monterey

I'm looking to disable my MacBook Pro (2016)'s internal keyboard.  I'm running macOS Monterey 12.6.3.  My left shift key is broken and always pressed, and while I have a Bluetooth keyboard that helps when I'm typing, other computer functionality acts as if the shift key is pressed (e.g. opening new pages creates new windows, clicking text highlights sections, etc.).

I have tried every solution I've come across: I took the keycap off and cleaned the key; I used a keyboard cleaner software to lock up my keyboard; I used Karabiner-Elements to disable my built-in while my external keyboard was active; I ran a keyboard-disabling kext in Terminal.  None of these things have worked for even a second.

I can't help but feel that maybe because these solutions are all a few years old, they're out of date and no longer work on Apple's OS, so if anyone has any other solutions I could try, please let me know!  I'm also not ruling out that I've messed up somewhere in trying these solutions, but I've tried so many different things, I'd think one would work.

Comment: Which specific command did you run to disable kext in Terminal, which *specific* Karabiner rules did you use? Details may matter, so without knowing them you may just get the same answers again.

Comment: I specifically used the Karabiner rule that disables the internal keyboard when an external keyboard is connected (from the section devices>advanced).  The kext I used was actually the same one that Thinkr posted below.

Comment: So I rebooted my computer and Karabiner Elements started working.  I need to reset Karabiner every so often to get it to kick in, but my internal keyboard is now disabled (most of the time)!  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Terminal: Open Terminal and enter:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext
```

You will need to enter your Mac password and then it will disable the internal keyboard of your Mac.

PS: You may need to reboot to make it work.

Comment: Your command doesn‘t use AppleScript.

Comment: Terminal runs a shell (usually bash or zsh), the shell runs binaries. In this case you run `sudo` which then runs `kextunload`. See `man sudo` and `man kextunload` for details (and read some introductory shell texts).

Comment: Basically, both shell scripting and AppleScript are examples of scripting languages. AppleScript works on a totally different level, it interacts with macOS directly (kind of).

Comment: For further studies: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html, https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html.