# Recently updated OS and now all clicks are command + clicks. How to disable or diagnose this?

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura

OS: Ventura 13.3.1

After a recent update, chrome and the os in general seem to think that the command key is being held down for every click.  All links open in new tabs, clicking an icon in the dock launches finder, etc... I'm really looking for help diagnosing where this is coming from.

The truth is, it may have nothing to do with the OS update.  Around the same time, I built and installed [Alacritty terminal](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) from source.  I have since uninstalled it to try and fix this problem, but no luck.

I would very much appreciate any advice on how I might diagnose this issue.  I'm at a bit of a loss at the moment.  I'd rather not restore from a backup, but this is a pretty annoying bug.

Comment: Do you have another keyboard/mouse combo you can test with? Things break, especially when you need them most. In a pinch, you can try a Windows-centric USB keyboard & mouse for troubleshooting.

Comment: Following the idea proposed by @IconDaemon, I suggest you use an external keyboard (not mouse - the problem seems to be that the command key is forever pressed) and you disable the Mac's internal keyboard (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457054/489896). To re-enable it, just replace `kextunload` by `kextload` and re-run the whole command.

Comment: I've had computer mouses cause problems when plugged in, and the problems stop when unplugged. As mechanical and electrical devices, they can introduce some interference or spurious electrical signals into the USB path which might be problematic.